# error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand when passing std::string

Tags: c++

I am writing C++ code and I am using a struct.

```
struct Info_t {
    cass_int64_t internal_id;
    cass_double_t amount;
    std::string client;
}
```

I am passing a pointer to this struct in a function and I am using it like this

```
get_string(row_by_name(row, "cl"), &info->client.c_str());
```

but the compiler complains with error "*error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand"

The third argument of the row_by_name should be const char* and I am passing a std::string that I am trying to make it char* with c_str(). What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `&` there?

Comment: show the definition of `get_string` (and explain what it does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape the error just write

```
get_string(row_by_name(row, "cl"), info->client.c_str());
```

You may not apply operator & to temporary objects. This expression

```
info->client.c_str()
```

already has type `const char *`.

However it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you should declare the corresponding parameter as for example `const std::string &` and pass as the argument the object of `std::string` itself?

If the corresponding parameter is declared like const char ** though that is strange, then before passing the argument you have to declare an intermediate variable for example like this

const char *p =  info->client.c_str();

and pass it as argument using expression `&p`

Comment: Maybe a reference would be better, no?

Comment: If I remove &, I still take error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘const char**’

Comment: @cateof See my updated post. But I think that you are doing something wrong in general.